# BI and Self Service Reporting Tools that Support Web (HTML) Interface?

Tags: business-intelligence

Hopefully a simple question.  What BI tools (commercial or OSS) support self-service reporting or self-service BI via an HTML web interface?

I specified HTML because I know of at least one that can do it via the web, but only in Silverlight.

Comment: Cognos BI.. Commercial though..

Answer (score 2):

Pentaho.

There's Jaspersoft too, but I found Pentaho a little more useful, though Japser is prettier.

Comment: +1 for Pentaho. Its been around for years.